# tx_news arkicle title is not appearing on Facebook, Twitter and Xing

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

When I post this tx_news article link on different social media plattforms:

www.meinedomain/news-article/title-of-article/ (ex hidden: www.meinedomain/company/media-press/news-article/title-of-article/)

... instead of the News Article Title, I'll get intemedate path 'News Article' as header title of the post in Facebook, Xing and Twitter:

```
Facebook:
Link: yes
Picture: yes
Headline: News Articles and not Title
Teaser: yes

Xing:
Link: yes
Picture: yes
Headline: News Articles and not Title
Teaser: yes

Linkedin:
Link: yes
Picture: yes
Headline: yes
Teaser: no

Google+:
Link: yes
Picture: yes
Headline: yes
Teaser: no

Twitter:
Link: yes
Picture: yes
Headline: News Articles and not Title
Teaser: yes
```

How can I get the desired header on Facebook, Xing and Twitter as well? I'm also using tx_metaseo if relevant

Thats my source code:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Some Title - Weekly Update (June 12-18, 2017)" />
<meta property="og:url" content="mydomain/news-articles/some-title-weekly-update-june-12-18-2017/" />
...
<title>News Articles&nbsp;&#124; Some Company</title>
...
<meta name="DCTERMS.title" content="News Articles">
...
<meta property="og:title" content="News Articles">
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in your source code the `og:title` tag is given twice. Look at your typoscript if you set the `og:title` tag manually. Disable the typoscript `og:title` for your news detail page so the fluid `og:title` is the only one.

Comment: I would guess that metaseo is cutting the game here. The news extension creates the `title` and `og:title` tags already, metaseo seems to override that again. Disable metaseo on the news detail page.

Comment: Yes that was it. So I deactivated the metaseo og:title for the detail view of the news article in the template setup like [globalVar = TSFE:id = 97] plugin.metaseo.metaTags.opengraph = 0 [end] and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Things to check:

- is the `title`-tag correct on the website?
  if not: check the tx_news single view Fluid template
- is the OpenGraph data correct?
  if not: check the tx_news open graph output in the Fluid template
- is the title of the news article also the (first) `h1` of the page?
  if not: check the layout and header structure of the website

Comment: I'm not sure. I can see the above source code. I assume the title-tag is already not the way it should be? Please see above